# Sanitize XML Attribute Values

Tags: c#, .net, xml, serialization, xattribute

How can i easily sanitize the values I pass into the Value property of an XAttribute.

Comment: Define "sanitize" and you might get a useful answer.

Comment: Well basically its throwing an error on save that it cant accept a certain character, '/0'. I assume there are other chars it cannot accept, so i was wondering if there is a method to remove them all.

Comment: maybe add that info to the actual question...

Answer (score 1):

Here's an extension method to clean away your trouble. /0 is not allowed in XML. I'm not sure if other chars are also disallowed, but I believe not. Probably best to start at `' '`.

```
void Main()
{

    Console.WriteLine("123\0394".XmlSanitize());

}

public static class XmlHelpers
{
    public static string XmlSanitize(this string badString)
    {
        return new String(badString.Where(c => c >=' ').ToArray());
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try:

```
string value = "!@#$%^&*()123%^&*(!@#\(*!&10987"
value = System.Security.SecurityElement.Escape(value);
```

This will escape characters that are invalid as XML attribute values.

Comment: Nice, but doesn't get rid of the \0.